# Node js and Redis filter data based on condition

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am setting up my data in redis as key value pair like this

`let data = [{key: 'a-9' , val: 'a'}, {key: 'a-7', val: 'b'}, {key: 'b-8', val: 'c'}]`

and want to get back data based on a condition like this

All 'a' keys which are greater than or equal to 9

```
client.hgetAsync("class_cache", "a").then(res => {
    callback(null, res);               
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
}).finally(() => {
    client.quit();
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check the Redis module https://redisearch.io ?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Only globs in the pattern are checked for a match. Supported patterns are the same as used for the KEYS command, which is described here: http://redis.io/commands/keys

you can get the object form data, and process object with javascript command

```
let data = [{key: 'a-9' , val: 'a'}, {key: 'a-7', val: 'b'}, {key: 'b-8', val: 'c'}]
let result = []
data.forEach(element => {
  if(element.key.split('-')[1] > 8)
  result.push(element)
});
console.log(result);
```